# Explaining a model built with BERT using SHAP with RepeatDataset and BatchDataset type objects

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model, shap

I have built a bit complex model using pretrained BERT weights. The model structure is as follows:

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_ids (InputLayer)          [(None, 32)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
attention_mask (InputLayer)     [(None, 32)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
token_type_ids (InputLayer)     [(None, 32)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_bert_model_1 (TFBertModel)   ((None, 32, 768), (N 109482240   input_ids[0][0]                  
                                                                 attention_mask[0][0]             
                                                                 token_type_ids[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_76 (Dropout)            (None, 32, 768)      0           tf_bert_model_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                   (None, 256)          1049600     dropout_76[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 128)          32896       lstm_1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_77 (Dropout)            (None, 128)          0           dense_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)                 (None, 64)           8256        dropout_77[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)                 (None, 32)           2080        dense_6[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)                 (None, 16)           528         dense_7[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)                 (None, 7)            119         dense_8[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 110,575,719
Trainable params: 110,575,719
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I have used RepeatDataset type objects to feed the data to the model. It is created with the following code:

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_inp,train_mask,train_type_ids,train_out)).map(convert_to_features).shuffle(100).batch(BATCH_SIZE).repeat(5)
type(test_ds)
```

So the type is: `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.RepeatDataset`. Now I want to add model explanation using [SHAP](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

I have already tried to make an implementation using the `DeepExplainer`. It tries to get the shape of the data, in my case the `train_ds`. But being a `RepeateDataset` type of object it has no shape attribute. How can I overcome the model? Or is there any other way to use SHAP with `RepeatDataset` type objects?

Comment: A [reprex] may help